# how to parse Json using retrofit2

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, retrofit2

> i have some json response.
>   help me to parse this response in retrofit2 
>    {
>           "status": "success",
>           "code": "200",
>           "messages": {
>           "Old Songs": [
>           {
>           "id": "8",
>           "name": "tttt",
>           "album_image": "admin/upload/default_album_300_g4.png"
>           },
>           {
>           "id": "9",
>           "name": "ggggg",
>           "album_image": "admin/upload/Jellyfish.jpg"
>           }
>           ],
>           "Latest Songs": [
>           {
>           "id": "9",
>           "name": "ggggg",
>           "album_image": "admin/upload/Jellyfish.jpg"
>           }
>           ]
>           }
>           }
>   all pojo class of my Json is.....

```
public class Example {

@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private String status;
@SerializedName("code")
@Expose
private String code;
@SerializedName("messages")
@Expose
private Messages messages;

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}

public Messages getMessages() {
    return messages;
}

public void setMessages(Messages messages) {
    this.messages = messages;
}
```

}

```
public class Messages extends ArrayList<Messages> {

@SerializedName("Old Songs")
@Expose
private List<OldSong> oldSongs = null;
@SerializedName("Latest Songs")
@Expose
private List<LatestSong> latestSongs = null;

public List<OldSong> getOldSongs() {
    return oldSongs;
}

public void setOldSongs(List<OldSong> oldSongs) {
    this.oldSongs = oldSongs;
}

public List<LatestSong> getLatestSongs() {
    return latestSongs;
}

public void setLatestSongs(List<LatestSong> latestSongs) {
    this.latestSongs = latestSongs;
}
```

}

```
public class OldSong {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("album_image")
@Expose
private String albumImage;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAlbumImage() {
    return albumImage;
}

public void setAlbumImage(String albumImage) {
    this.albumImage = albumImage;
}
```

}

```
public class LatestSong {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("album_image")
@Expose
private String albumImage;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAlbumImage() {
    return albumImage;
}

public void setAlbumImage(String albumImage) {
    this.albumImage = albumImage;
}
```

}

> My MainActivity class is...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener {
Button send;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    send=(Button)findViewById(R.id.send);
    send.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    /**
     * Checking Internet Connection
     */
    if (InternetConnection.checkConnection(getApplicationContext())) {
        final ProgressDialog dialog;
        /**
         * Progress Dialog for User Interaction
         */
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setTitle("json load");
        dialog.setMessage("getting json");
        dialog.show();
        //Creating an object of our api interface
        ApiService api = RetroClient.getApiService();

        /**
         * Calling JSON
         */
        Call<Example> call = api.getMyJSON();
        /**
         * Enqueue Callback will be call when get response...
         */
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                    //want here to parse  response

                } else {
                    Snackbar.make(parentView,"something wrong" , Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Example> call, Throwable t) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

    } else {
        Snackbar.make(parentView, "internet_connection_not_available", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: dig into google you will find lot of answers. If any error you face then post it

Answer (score 1):

you have to creat classes like below.

```
    public class LatestSong {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("album_image")
@Expose
private String albumImage;

public String getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public String getAlbumImage() {
return albumImage;
}

public void setAlbumImage(String albumImage) {
this.albumImage = albumImage;
}

}
```

Class 2:

```
public class Messages {

@SerializedName("Old Songs")
@Expose
private List<OldSong> oldSongs = null;
@SerializedName("Latest Songs")
@Expose
private List<LatestSong> latestSongs = null;

public List<OldSong> getOldSongs() {
return oldSongs;
}

public void setOldSongs(List<OldSong> oldSongs) {
this.oldSongs = oldSongs;
}

public List<LatestSong> getLatestSongs() {
return latestSongs;
}

public void setLatestSongs(List<LatestSong> latestSongs) {
this.latestSongs = latestSongs;
}

}
```

Class 3:

```
public class OldSong {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("album_image")
@Expose
private String albumImage;

public String getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public String getAlbumImage() {
return albumImage;
}

public void setAlbumImage(String albumImage) {
this.albumImage = albumImage;
}

}
```

Class 4:

```
public class Response {

@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private String status;
@SerializedName("code")
@Expose
private String code;
@SerializedName("messages")
@Expose
private Messages messages;

public String getStatus() {
return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
this.status = status;
}

public String getCode() {
return code;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
this.code = code;
}

public Messages getMessages() {
return messages;
}

public void setMessages(Messages messages) {
this.messages = messages;
}

}
```

Now you have to set `Response.class` to your retrofit.

Comment: i have all that pojo class but i want parsing of this Json